# I need to get pandas-dataframe rows, that includes specific value on specific list's place in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns. One of this column's type is list:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[1, 2, 'x'], ['as', 3, 5, 7], [1, 2]],
                   'col2': ['barfoo', 'foo', 'bar']})
print(df)
            col1    col2
0      [1, 2, x]  barfoo
1  [as, 3, 5, 7]     foo
2         [1, 2]     bar
```

So I need to get rows, where values of lists in 'col1' equals 2.

Something like this (It doesn't works):

```
result = df.loc[df['col1'].list[1] == 2]
```

Desired output:

```
            col1    col2
0      [1, 2, x]  barfoo
2         [1, 2]     bar
```

Answer (score 0):

you cound do:

```
df.loc[df.col1.str[1] == 2]
```

Comment: Lol. Very surprised that works. Thank you

Comment: Glad I've been of help